Can send an SSL message via mosquitto but getting CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED from python paho script
Using mosquitto:
mosquitto_pub -h <public ip address> -t testssl/topic -m "hello  world" --cafile ./ca_certificate.pem -p 8883 --tls-version tlsv1.2 -d --id client2

Client client2 sending CONNECT
Client client2 received CONNACK (0)
Client client2 sending PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m1, 'testssl/topic', ... (12 bytes))
Client client2 sending DISCONNECT

Using python paho script:
# python 3.11
import datetime
import json
import random
import time
import uuid

from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt_client

from config import broker, port, topic

# Generate a Client ID with the publish prefix.
client_id = f'publish-{random.randint(0, 100)}'

def connect_mqtt():
    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc == 0:
            print("Connected to MQTT Broker!")
        else:
            print("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc)

    client = mqtt_client.Client(client_id)
    client.tls_set(
        ca_certs="ca_certificate.pem",
        tls_version=mqtt_client.ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2,
    )
    # client.username_pw_set("rw", "readwrite")
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.connect(broker, port)
    return client

def fake_sensor_data():
    """Generate a fake sensor data event."""
    list_of_sensor_ids = [ uuid.uuid4() for _ in range(10) ]
    values = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ]
    return {
        "timestamp": time.time(),
        "device_id": str(list_of_sensor_ids[random.randint(0, 9)]),
        "event": {
            "payload": values[random.randint(0, 8)],
        }
    }



def publish(client):
    while True:
        time.sleep(3)
        msg = json.dumps(fake_sensor_data())
        result = client.publish(topic, msg)
        status = result[0]
        if status == 0:
            print()
            print(datetime.datetime.now(), msg)


def run():
    print("Connecting to MQTT Broker")
    print(f"Broker: {broker}")
    print(f"Port: {port}")
    print(f"Topic: {topic}")
    client = connect_mqtt()
    print("Connected!")
    print("Ready to publish messages!")
    client.loop_start()
    publish(client)
    client.loop_stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()

Error:
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: IP address mismatch, certificate is not valid for '<public ip address>'. (_ssl.c:1006)

I generated the ca_certificate using tls-gen on my server in a script. Elsewhere I read that if I am providing a public ip address instead of a DNS name, I should be using a SAN, however tls-gen does not allow for me to specify one easily - would be good to not have to modify the server initiation script too much.
I would like to understand why mosquitto would work and python/paho needs a SAN for the same certificate file.

DNS hostnames and/or IP addresses should be in a SAN. The use of the CN in the subject to hold the hostname has been deprecated now for more than 24 years. I'm not kidding.

Thanks for the reply. So is mosquito then implemented incorrectly? Why does it "work" without specifying --insecure

I don't know which, if any, of these implementations is incorrect. Are you sure you provide the same IP address for command-line and python programs?

Following your advice I generated the certs I installed on rabbit mq servers with the SAN being the public IP address and successfully exchanged messages

The reason mosquitto verifies the certificate can be found in the mosquitto__verify_certificate_hostname function in the file lib/tls_mosq.c:
https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/15292b20b0894ec7c5c3d47e4b22ee9d89f91132/lib/tls_mosq.c#L128
This can be seen to check the SAN entries and only checks the CN if there is no SAN section in the certificate.
        if(have_san_dns){
            /* Only check CN if subjectAltName DNS entry does not exist. */
            return 0;
        }`


So without explicitly asking Roger (mosquitto maintainer) I expect this is just mosquitto still supporting the long deprecated option to use the CN where as Python has dropped that option.
Either way the best option is to produce a valid certificate with the correct SAN options (especially if using raw IP addresses)
